# Can I pick a specific item from generator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

With:

```
def merge(a, b):
    i = j = 0
    total = len(a) + len(b)
    while i + j < total:
        if j == len(b) or (i < len(a) and a[i] <= b[j]):
            yield a[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            yield b[j]
            j += 1
```

Can I just pick the third element from the generator or I have to iterate by `next()` three times?

Comment: You have to call next three times.

Comment: You have to iterate.

Comment: @SimeonVisser & @Ben, so `xrange` would also do the same when it's used? Does calling the next have any memory usage?

Comment: xrange just returns a generator - all generators work in the same way. You can't slice them.

Comment: @Ben, that is not True `x=xrange()print(x[2])`), you can index the third element

Comment: Interesting! How does that work then?

Comment: @Ben xrange in Py2 and range in Py3 return objects that support `__getitem__` method. They aren't iterators like generator objects are. The difference is, range in Python 2 returns a list, whereas xrange will never store all the elements in memory.

Comment: @Ben, xrange supports three things iteration, len and indexing.

Comment: Seems like the indexing support is through `islice`. Not?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Despite the fact that [the relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange) agrees with you, `xrange`s in my copy of Python 2.7.9 also support `in` checks and reversed iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) in combination with `next`. However this will consume steps in your generator so it's effectively the same as calling `next` three times and picking up the third value. It's just a more abstract way of doing it.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> g = (i for i in range(10))
>>> next(islice(g, 2, 2 + 1))
2
>>> next(g)
3
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  Generators are iterators (they have `__next__` method), range objects aren't. I only wanted to illustrate that using `islice` advances the iterator state of a generator object.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham True but the question is for generators, which are a subclass of iterators.